# How to create a datetime aware for Django in UTC

Tags: django, datetime

I have configured my timezone in settings, as `America/Guatemala` and I have some datetime fields in my models, I'm using `default=timezone.now` but it is not saving my local hour, which is UTC-6:00, is saving it as UTC-00:00. I can't change that because now there is some important data stored in the database in that way.

I have problems retrieving the data in a queryset, I send a string in `request.POST` like this:

```
date='1/09/2016'
```

And I have tried this to configure my date for the query:

```
f=date.split('/') 
if len(f)>1:
    initialdate=datetime.datetime(int(f[2]),int(f[1]),int(f[0]),0,0,0,tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
    finaldate=datetime.datetime(int(f[2]),int(f[1]),int(f[0]),23,59,59,tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
```

And this is my queryset:

```
sale=Sale.objects.filter(Q(pk=int(cod))|Q(sale_date__range=(initialdate,finaldate)))
```

But because of the 6 hours of difference between my saved data and my local date and time, if I store a Sale at 6:01pm of my local time, the saved data is stored as 00:01am of tomorrow. If i want to check all the sales that I made today, it doesn't show me the sales after 6pm, because they are saved in a different date.

I have another queries where I send two differents dates, and I use the same code, I just add time `0,0,0` to the first date, and `23,59,59` to the second date, but I have the same problem.

My question is, how can I add those six hours to the dates that I use as parameters? I need the datetime to be aware, and I can't change nothing in my model, I can change only the parameters that I'm sending to the queryset.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but I wrestled with time zone formats and math until reading this blog post. Hopefully it is helpful to you as well: (Time Zones in Pytz & Django | https://tommikaikkonen.github.io/timezones/)

Answer (score 0):

I am also have the question. and what I am did is that:
the whole day's date range is: 00:00:00 - 23:59:59, and this is the local datetime, but the datetime in datebase has beed transformed to utc, so I just sub the local datetime 6 hour, and you can do so；

```
import datetime

f=date.split('/') 
if len(f)>1:
    initialdate=datetime.datetime(int(f[2]),int(f[1]),int(f[0]),0,0,0,tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
    finaldate=datetime.datetime(int(f[2]),int(f[1]),int(f[0]),23,59,59,tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
    initialdate = initialdate - datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
    finaldate = finaldate - datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to make date aware**

To simply change the date six hours back you can use `datetime`'s `timedelta`.

To change `sale_date` of objects within your query you simply need to do this:

```
import datetime
import pytz
for s in sale:
    sale_date = sale_date - datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
    sale_date = sale_date.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone("America/Guatemala"))
    s.save()
```

To change `sale_date` of all `Sale` objects:

```
import datetime
import pytz
all_sales =  Sale.objects.all()
for sale in all_sales:
    sale_date = sale_date - datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
    sale_date = sale_date.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone("America/Guatemala"))
    sale.save()
```

Also, to parse strings containing time information use `strptime`:

```
import datetime
date='1/09/2016'
parsed_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%w/%m%Y')
```

More info on it [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pytz
from django.utils import timezone

initialdate = datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time.min.replace(tzinfo=timezone.UTC())).astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/Guatemala'))

finaldate = datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time.max.replace(tzinfo=timezone.UTC())))).astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/Guatemala'))
```

Comment: I have tried your code, it takes the six hours from today's minimum and maximum hours, but there's a problem, in my local time are 22:11 hours of september 12, and the server has 4:11 hours of september 13, so it has an extra day. When substarction is made, it gives me in initialdate= 18:00 of september 12, and finaldate= 18:00 of september 13. So, if in my local time I made a sale at 4pm, and I want to chek today's sales at 10pm, I can only see the sales that were made after 18:00pm, before sales are not shown. How can I solve this?

Comment: What is your version of Django? Since version 1.9 django has `date` field lookup (https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#date). 
In this case you can do smth like that `Sale.objects.filter(sale_date__date=initialdate)` where `initialdate=timezone.now().astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/Guatemala')).date()` What is your the database?

Comment: Or you can take your local time, convert it to server timezone and than combine with time.min / time.max.